# Artifactory in Docker redirecting to different Port

Tags: docker, http, artifactory

So i deployed Artifactory OSS in Docker using these commands:

```
#docker volume create artifactory-oss_data
#docker run  --name artifactory -d -v artifactory-oss_data:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory -p 8081:8081 docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest
```

So far the container is starting and running.
Now when I navigate to

```
http://<DOCKERHOST>:8081/
```

it redirects me to

```
http://<DOCKERHOST>:8082/ui/
```

Here are the network stats:

[image]
[image]
[image]

And [here](https://pastebin.com/en02jugb) are the Artifactory logs.

What is the problem here? I did specify the port and it redirects me to a different port.
I have also the same problem with

Comment: Artifactory uses more than one port

Comment: This is expected behavior. UI is on port 8082 now.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a problem but expected behavior as you have installed Artifactory version 7.x and the Artifactory version 6.x, please refer to this [wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/System+Requirements) on the system requirements for Artifactory v7.x. Please refer to this [wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Platform+Overview) on Artifactory 7. This [wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-DockerInstallation) talks about installing Artifactory version 7 and this [wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Installing+with+Docker) for installing Artifactory version 6.

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish 8082 port for UI as well. So your command should looks like:

```
docker run  --name artifactory -d -v artifactory-oss_data:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory -p 8081:8081 -p 8082 docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

We should expose more than one port, i.e. 8081 and 8082. Artifactory REST APIs use 8081 and all others use 8082.

E.g:
docker run --name artifactory -d -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-cpp-ce:latest